# sent bit coin cash to coin base by mistake

Tags: bitcoin-cash, coinbase.com

hey guys i sent 300$ of bit coin cash to my coin base account coin base does not support bit coin cash but i can see that the transaction went threw and was verified  more than 41 times. the address it was sent to was generated by my coin base account so im not worried about someone else having my money i was wondering if there was some way to get that bitcoin cash out of there some how i cant see it on coin base because they only have bit coin but i know the address.

thank you 
Rachel

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to contact Coinbase to get your bch back, the coins are in a bch address controlled by coinbase.